# Chrome mobile ignoring overflow

Tags: android, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm playing around with creating a webapp for android. I've been using phonegap with JQM, but I've reached a problem.

I'm implementing a slide-in menu, and for that I've found a simple example on the internet.

http://www.aldomatic.com/jqm/fb-menu-style/

This simple menu slides in from the left, and that part works great, but when i try to slide it in i get a problem. The whole page scrolls, and this is despite me having

```
#mobileViewport {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

(The body tag has the id of `mobileViewport`

I have tried adding it to the html tag too, but to no avail.

Is this a bug? and is there any workaround?

Answer (score 1):

By default, JQM pages are positioned **absolutely**, outside of the flow of their containing element (if the containing element is statically positioned).

Adding `overflow:hidden` on the containing element (body) is therefore not going to help.

If you apply `position:relative` to `#mobileViewport` that should cause the JQM mobile pages to now flow correctly from the containing element and the `overflow:hidden` should work.

However, I suspect that is probably not a good idea and bound to cause other CSS display issues. (I recall playing around with that myself one time and having other issues as a side-effect)

Probably a better idea is adding the overflow:hidden to the JQM page elements themselves.

```
<body class="ui-mobile-viewport">
  <div id="mypage" data-role="page" class="ui-page">
  ...
  </div>
</div>

#mypage {
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

NOTE: If you have a footer, you might want to apply the `overflow:hidden` to the child `.ui-content`  element instead.