# Overflow hidden not working on mobile devices on body

Tags: html, css

I have some jQuery that sets overflow:hidden to the html body while a modal is open. Works just fine on all desktop browsers.

However, this isn't working for mobile. From what I've read, overflow:hidden gets ignored by mobile browsers when it's within the body tag for some reason.

I've read that wrapping your content within a div and setting that overflow:hidden is a solution but it's not really one for me.

Any other ideas out there? Anyone else encounter this issue?

Comment: is overflow:hidden set on `html,body` or just `body`?

Comment: I believe it is overflow-x and overflow-y that is not recognized by mobile browsers. Overflow:hidden should work just fine.

Comment: overflow:hidden is applied to both body and html. This does not fix the issue.

Comment: Can you add a live example?

Answer (score -2):

try

```
html, body {
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Could you add more detail to your answer? While short answers may help by pointing in the right direction, it would be helpful to have further explanation.

Answer (score -2):

add `position:relative;` with `overflow: hidden;` and see if that works.

Comment: you don't need to add a "-1". Tried to help you =))

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Overflow: hidden could get ignored cause of "position: absolute;". Take a look here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14094433/chrome-mobile-ignoring-overflow 
or here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288938/mobile-android-ios-browsers-are-ignoring-overflow-hidden-on-body-html-and